# How to stop the link to open if session is expired

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have web application deployed on jboss server and report war deployed on Tomcat server , in web application there is report section which refers birt report deployed on tomcat using "href" link in JSP.

Now when though session gets expired user is able to open the link and see the information.

How can we stop this?

Any suggestion is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I correctly understand, the web app runs on a JBoss server, and the resport one on a Tomcat. When you say *the session is expired* which one are you refering ? The one on JBoss ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is what you can do to check if the `session` has expired:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); // Don't create a session
if(null == session) {
   // Handle the null session case here. Disallow download and what not
}
```

Having, said that I am sure that your valid user session would be more than that. If you are setting a token or userId in the session you can check for its presence also before letting the download happen.

```
if(session.hasAttribute("token")) {
   // Let the download happen.
}
```

Also, please note that `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)` would lead to the creation of a new session if it does not exist already.